# Finding the first combination of two integers in an array whose latter element appears the earliest and sum matches a given value

Tags: arrays, ruby, combinations

I have `array` and `sum_of_two`:

```
array = [10, 5, 1, 9, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 7, 5]
sum_of_two = 10
```

I'm trying to find the combination of two integers in `array` whose latter element of the two appears the earliest among those of such combinations whose sum equals `sum_of_two`. For example, both `[5, 5]` and `[1, 9]` are candidates for such combinations, but `9` of `[1, 9]` (which appears later than `1` in `array`) appears earlier than the second `5` of `[5, 5]` (which is the last element in `array`). So I would like to return `[1, 9]`.

I tried using `combination` and `find`:

```
array.combination(2).find{|x,y| x + y == sum_of_two} #=> [5, 5]
```

However, it returns a combination of the first integer in the array, `5` , and another integer further along the array, also `5`.

If I use `find_all` instead of `find`, I get all combinations of two integers that add up to `sum_of_two`:

```
array.combination(2).find_all{|x,y| x + y == sum_of_two}
#=> [[5, 5], [1, 9], [1, 9], [9, 1], [7, 3], [8, 2], [8, 2], [2, 8], [4, 6], [6, 4], [9, 1], [3, 7], [2, 8]]
```

But then I'm not sure how to get the first one.

Comment: In what sense is `[1, 9]` the first combination as opposed to `[5, 5]`?

Comment: It is the first combination to appear from the left. As in if you were to read the array from left to right. Is there a better way of explaining it? I tried writing in 'order of appearance' (from the left) as I thought that was the best way to explain it.

Comment: Going from left to right, don't you hit `5` first before `1` or `9`?

Comment: Yes but the second 5 is at the end of the array. So `1` and `9` are the first combination that equal `sum_of_two` along the array. So lets say you read the array one element at a time, you would read `10`, `5`, `1`, `9`, and then  'that's it' you found your first combination along the array.

Comment: The order of individual elements is defined, but the notion: "the first combination" is not defined unless you define it.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. How would you define it based on my previous comment? I would chat if needs be but don't have enough reputation yet haha. Nice to speak to you again sawa. I hope this is at least an upstep from my last posted question.

Comment: I described it for you.

Comment: Many thanks. I was thinking of it in terms of reading left to right, rather than the 2nd element appearing earlier. That in itself is also why I was struggling with how to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) (which would be a bit more efficient than using `Array#include?`) and do something like this:

```
array = [10, 5, 1, 9, 7, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 7, 5]
sum_of_two = 10

require 'set'

array.each_with_object(Set.new) do |element, set| 
  if set.include?(sum_of_two - element)
    break [sum_of_two - element, element]
  else
    set << element
  end
end
#=> [1, 9]
```

Comment: Interesting. I haven't come across 'set' yet so I'll have a look into this further. And I'll make sure to upvote both answers once I have enough rep :-) Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
x = array.find.with_index{|e, i| array.first(i).include?(sum_of_two - e)}
[sum_of_two - x, x] # => [1, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array#combination(n)` does not give the elements in the order you want, so you must build the pairs yourself. It's easy if you begin from the second index. A O(n) lazy implementation, and let's call the input `xs`:

```
pairs = (1...xs.size).lazy.flat_map { |j| (0...j).lazy.map { |i| [xs[i], xs[j]] } }
first_matching_pair = pairs.detect { |i, j| i + j == 10 }
#=> [1, 9]
```